# App Store Connect: Is there a REST API to fetch all apps in a bundle?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, app-store-connect, subscription

We are implementing bundle supscription. Is there a way to fetch all apps in an app bundle from App StoreConnect?

App bundle ref: Ref: developer.apple.com/app-store/app-bundles

Comment: @dbugger the above is to get bundle id information. my requirement is to fetch app bundle which can contain many apps. 
Ref: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-bundles/